# Inverse FFT with CMSIS is wrong

Tags: arm, embedded, fft, stm32, cmsis

I am attempting to perform an FFT on a signal and use the resulting data to retrieve the original samples via an IFFT. I am using the CMSIS DSP library on an STM32 with a M3.

My issue is understanding the scaling that occurs with the FFT, and also how to get a correct IFFT. Currently the IFFT results in a similar wave as the input, but points are scaled anywhere between 120x-140x of the original. Is this simply the result of precision errors of q15? Am I too scale the IFFT results by 7 bits? My code is below

The documentation also mentions "For the RIFFT, the source buffer must at least have length fftLenReal + 2. The last two elements must be equal to what would be generated by the RFFT: (pSrc[0] - pSrc[1]) >> 1 and 0". What is this for? Applying these operations to FFT_SIZE*2 - 2, and FFT_SIZE*2 - 1 respectively did not change the results of the IFFT at all.

```
//128 point FFT
#define FFT_SIZE 128
arm_rfft_instance_q15 fft_instance;
arm_rfft_instance_q15 ifft_instance;

//time domain signal buffers
float32_t sinetbl_in[FFT_SIZE];
float32_t sinetbl_out[FFT_SIZE];

//a copy for comparison after RFFT since function modifies input buffer
volatile q15_t fft_in_buf_cpy[FFT_SIZE];
q15_t fft_in_buf[FFT_SIZE];

//output for FFT, RFFT provides real and complex data organized as re[0], im[0], re[1], im[1]
q15_t fft_out_buf[FFT_SIZE*2];
q15_t fft_out_buf_mag[FFT_SIZE*2];

//inverse fft buffer result
q15_t ifft_out_buf[FFT_SIZE];

//generate 1kHz sinewave with a sample frequency of 8kHz for 128 samples, amplitude is 1
for(int i = 0; i < FFT_SIZE; ++i){
 sinetbl_in[i] = arm_sin_f32(2*3.14*1000 *i/8000);
 sinetbl_out[i] = 0;
}

//convert buffer to q15 (not enough flash to use f32 fft functions)
arm_float_to_q15(sinetbl_in, fft_in_buf, FFT_SIZE);
memcpy(fft_in_buf_cpy, fft_in_buf, FFT_SIZE*2);

//perform RFFT
arm_rfft_init_q15(&fft_instance, FFT_SIZE, 0, 1);
arm_rfft_q15(&fft_instance, fft_in_buf, fft_out_buf);

//calculate magnitude, skip 1st real and img numbers as they are DC and both real
arm_cmplx_mag_q15(fft_out_buf + 2, fft_out_buf_mag + 1, FFT_SIZE/2-1);

//weird operations described by documentation, does not change results
//fft_out_buf[FFT_SIZE*2 - 2] = (fft_out_buf[0] - fft_out_buf[1]) >> 1;
//fft_out_buf[FFT_SIZE*2 - 1] = 0;

//perform inverse FFT
arm_rfft_init_q15(&ifft_instance, FFT_SIZE, 1, 1);
arm_rfft_q15(&ifft_instance, fft_out_buf, ifft_out_buf);

//closest approximation to get to original scaling
//arm_shift_q15(ifft_out_buf, 7, ifft_out_buf, FFT_SIZE);

//convert back to float for comparison with input
arm_q15_to_float(ifft_out_buf, sinetbl_out, FFT_SIZE);
```

I feel like I answered my own question with the precision comment, but I'd like to be sure. Am I doing this FFT stuff right?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If the output of `ifft(fft(f))` is a scaled version of `f`, then you likely have an unnormalized IFFT. Note [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Inverse_transform) that the inverse transform is typically normalized by 1/N, but some libraries skip this normalization because it is sometimes not needed. If you do need it, they expect you to apply the normalization yourself. The documentation should describe this.

Comment: I am not saying that this is incorrect but why do you exclude the first post-FFT value?
I mean, I know that according to docs "first complex sample contains two real values packed" instead of a complex number because it carries 0Hz value (=DC or offset) but still, are you certain this value should be excluded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cris pointed out some libraries skip the normalization process. CMSIS DSP is one of those libraries as it is intended to be fast. For CMSIS, depending on the FFT size you must left shift your data a certain amount to get back to the original range. In my case with a FFT size of 128 and also the magnitude calculation, it was 7 as I originally surmised.